# R subsetting by specific level combinations of 2 factors

Tags: r, subset

Subset based on unique combination of levels from 2 factors:

```
test <- data.frame(colA = rep(1:3,each =4), colB = LETTERS[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,5,6,7,4)] )
# select for each colA factor specfic letters: 1&A 1&B  2&E  3&D
test[test$colA %in% c(1,1,2,3) & test$colB %in% c("A", "B", "E", "D"),]
```

This is not what I want:

```
colA colB
1     1    A
2     1    B
4     1    D
5     2    E
7     2    A
8     2    B
9     3    E
12    3    D
```

I want:

```
colA colB
1 A
1 B
2 E
3 D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
> test[interaction(test,sep='') %in% c('1A','1B','2E','3D'),]
   colA colB
1     1    A
2     1    B
5     2    E
12    3    D
```

I imagine your actual situation may be more complicated, in which case you might want to build the acceptable combinations programmatically, like:

```
x <- paste(c(1,1,2,3), c('A','B','E','D'), sep='')
test[interaction(test,sep='') %in% x,]
```